# Meaning and etymology of "Crabbit"

Tags: meaning, etymology, meaning-in-context

What does this phrase mean?

> Being a **crabbit** is not gonna make it any easier for you.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.google.com/search?q=define:crabbit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crabbit is a Scots English, or Scottish dialect, word meaning "crabbed", in the sense of being miserable, negative and dour.  The word comes from "crab", and I presume is an anthropomorphism of the behaviour/appearance of crabs.

See Merriam-Webster [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crabbed) for definition of "crabbed" and [here](http://www.firstfoot.com/dictionary/c.html) for a couple of definitions of "crabbit".

My in-laws, being Scottish, regularly use "crabbit" to mean grumpy or miserable.